# Problem with css not loading fast enough on vuejs app

Tags: css, vue.js

On my vue PWA the css from vue bootstrap and buefy seems to undergo Slow loading of CSS.

I've tried V cloak, but it only hides components ms. after you see a see a glimpse of raw html with no css.

I'm trying to find a way on how to get a loader to show or something that hides the first milliseconds of html blocks or initially fix how the html blocks don't show without any style/don't show at all like on the gif below.

I appreciate any solutions here.

(Can't show image/gif here due to reputation rule)

[Click here for gif](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/DearestDefinitiveGecko-max-1mb.gif)

Answer (score 1):

The gif shows that the js is loaded before the css. This usually means that the css file is referenced too late in your index.html file. References (usually `<link>` elements) are loaded in the order that they're listed in html. Check your site in the inspector, and see where your css is listed

```
<link href="/app.js" rel="preload" as="script />
<link href="/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css"> ... </style>

// app.js should come first
```

This should be done automatically by vue-style-loader, which should be included in vue/cli-service. Are you using the vue cli?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved it all. I included css files from buefy and bootstrap in my main.scss file. This way the css was loaded the same time as js (How that exactly works 100% and the process behind it, I'm not sure about since I'm new to vue. I'm building themes on vue-storefront: (https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront)